# Verify an argument's type belongs to a hierarchy

Tags: python

Say I have a hierarchy e.g.:

```py
class Computer(object):
    def __init__(self, name, cpu):
        self.name = name
        self.cpu = cpu

class Laptop(Computer):
    def __init__(self, name, cpu, manufacturer):
        super().__init__(name, cpu)
        self.manufacturer = manufacturer

class AutomatedTellerMachine(Computer):
    def __init__(self, name, cpu, bank):
        super().__init__(name, cpu)
        self.bank = bank
```

how can I add type hints to function arguments, so that only objects in this hierarchy are accepted? I'm trying something like:

```py
def buy(item : Computer):
    pass # implementation here
```

but doesn't seem to correctly enforce the restriction when I run `mypy`

Comment: Can you also update the question with error message? For me `buy` working correctly with instances of `Computer`/ `Laptop `/ `AutomatedTellerMachine `

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM No error message, if I pass an integer to `buy`,  `mypy` says "Success: no issues found in 1 source file" , while I was expecting an error to occur, namely "int is not a Computer"

Comment: That's strange, for me mypy complaining with `error: Argument 1 to "buy" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Computer"`